# Autocomplete textfield

Tags: 7, entities

I've noticed that the autocomplete textfield widget has not been ported to Drupal 7.
I'm looking for a way to provide user with suggestion for already submitted values, but I don't want to create a free-tagging vocabulary, since I don't want a page with all nodes with a particular value.
What can I do? Has this feature been ported to a separate module like Node Reference?
I've tried Autocomplete Deluxe module, but it works only with terms, not with textfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references) provides autocomplete text fields for user and node references.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a textfield just to store a string, not a reference.

Comment: My point was that the functionality exists in D7, so it could be generalized or adapted. Plus you did mention Node Reference by name :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought Drupal 6 has this feature for textfield too, but I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original answer was written, some modules have appeared that do Autocomplete and/or dropdowns for textfields:

- [Autocomplete Widgets for Text and Number Fields](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets)
- [combo box field](http://drupal.org/project/combo-box)